# Existence of Real-Valued Functions Satisfying Certain Properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

(1)Please give a real-valued function $f$ satisfies the set $\{(x,f(x)):x\text{ belongs to }\mathbb{R}\}$ is a second category subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? 
(2)Please give a real-valued function f satisfies the set $\{(x,f(x)):x\text{ belongs to }\mathbb{R}\}$ is a non-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the Lebesgue sense?

Comment: but how do you proof the range of f is a second category subset of R2?

Comment: @mathabc: Mike’s function is a surjection: its range is *all* of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Whoops, you're right that doesn't work.

Comment: my mistake,what I mean is how to proof the graph of f is a second category subset of R2?

Answer (score 1):

See Gelbaum and Olmsted, Counterexamples in Analysis, Chapter 10, Plane Sets, Example 23, A real-valued function of one real variable whose graph is a nonmeasurable plane set. It's a little too long for me to type out, and it depends on Example 21, A nonmeasurable plane set having at most two points in common with any line. Example 21 takes two full pages in the book.

Comment: Thank you very much!For(1),do you have any ideas?

Comment: You may use space-filling curves, aka Peano curves.

Comment: For the first, wouldn't using a combination using a nonmeasurable subset of $\mathbb R^2$ help?

Comment: @gary, OP wants the graph of a function, which a Peano curve is not. Also, I don't know what "a combination using a nonmeasurable subset" means.

Comment: I meant somehow using the fact that the characteristic function of a nonmeasurable set is nonmeasurable.

Comment: why does the characteristic function of a nonmeasurable set work?

Comment: I don't think the characteristic function of a nonmeasurable set does work. A nonmeasurable subset of the real line is just a measure zero set when viewed as a subset of the plane.

Comment: I have found the two examples.Thank you very much for all your help.